# Android Wear: Can I change the look of the peak card?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I have started creating a watch face. I wish to change the [peek card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcegQ.png) to a custom image. In the image you see a red circle around the part I wish to change. I want to make a person pop up at the bottom of the screen so the user know's he has a notification, like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUuDV.jpg) here. Just think of the wall being the bottom of the watchface.

Is this possible?

Let me know,

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is most probably possible. Please refine the question to get a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can apply styles to your notifications, such as [`BigPictureStyle`, `BigTextStyle` or `IndexStyle`](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html#BigView).

Here is an example of using BigTextStyle:

```
// Specify the 'big view' content to display the long
// event description that may not fit the normal content text.
BigTextStyle bigStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
bigStyle.bigText(eventDescription);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_event)
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFractory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notif_background))
    .setContentTitle(eventTitle)
    .setContentText(eventLocation)
    .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_map, getString(R.string.map), mapPendingIntent)
    .setStyle(bigStyle);
```

You can create a layout in your Activity and embed it inside your notification: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html#CustomNotifications

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to replace the preview peek card which is encircled in red with another image. This answer only changed the big-style for the notification rather then the preview peek card.